# Typeahead google api on flows

Tags: visual-workflow, google-map

I currently have a custom page that accepts addresses as user input. This addresses use Google API in the back-end and gives user suggestions as they type. Due to some changes in the process, we longer can use a custom page.

I'm trying to figure out if a flow can replace custom page. I need suggestions(typeahead) as the user types on the UI with help of Google API call. Is this possible with flows?

I created some flow but not sure how make it work similar to the custom page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to extend you flow with an apex. Apex code will perform calls to Google API. [Extend Your Flow with Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_apex.htm)

But, I would recommend you out-of-the-box Salesforce functionality of lightning component called `lightning:inputAddress` with `showAddressLookup = "true"`. [lightning:inputAddress Specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputAddress/specification) Later, you can try to use this component in flows ([Aura Component Available For Flow Screens](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:availableForFlowScreens/documentation)).

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful